# Обновление и удаление записи в БД и в списке

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-sqlite

Создал БД в android, с созданием записей все хорошо, список заполняется, данные обновляются, но вот с изменение или удалением проблемы. Помогите, пожалуйста, курсовая под угрозой :)

Данные не обновляются при изменении.

```
public class NotebookDbAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notebook.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String NOTE_TABLE = "note";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";

    public String[] allColumns = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_MESSAGE, COLUMN_CATEGORY, COLUMN_DATE};

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = " create table " + NOTE_TABLE + " ( "
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_MESSAGE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_DATE + " LONG);";

    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
    private NotebookDbHelper notebookDbHelper;
    private Context context;

    public NotebookDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public NotebookDbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {

        notebookDbHelper = new NotebookDbHelper(context);
        sqlDB = notebookDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;

    }

    public void close() {

        notebookDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Note createNote(String title, String message, Note.Category category) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, message);
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, category.name());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "");

        long insertId = sqlDB.insert(NOTE_TABLE, null, values);

        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(NOTE_TABLE, allColumns, COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Note newNote = cursorToNote(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newNote;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }


    public long deleteNote(long idToDelete) {

        return sqlDB.delete(NOTE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + idToDelete, null);
    }

    public long updateNote(long idToUpdate, String newTitle, String newMessage, Note.Category newCategory) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, newTitle);
        values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, newMessage);
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, newCategory.name());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "");


        return sqlDB.update(NOTE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = " + idToUpdate, null);
    }


    public List<Note> getAllnotes() {

        List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(NOTE_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        for (cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
            Note note = cursorToNote(cursor);
            notes.add(note);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return notes;
    }

    private Note cursorToNote(Cursor cursor) {

        Note newNote = new Note(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), Note.Category.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)),
                cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getLong(4));
        return newNote;

    }

    private static class NotebookDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        NotebookDbHelper(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(NotebookDbHelper.class.getName(), "upgrading database from version " + newVersion + "to" + oldVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");

            String upquery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
            db.execSQL(upquery + NOTE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
}
```

**ListFragment:**

```
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {

private List<Note> notes;
private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /*
    String[] values = new String[] {"Note1","Note2","Note3","Note4","Note5",
        "Note6","Note7","Note8","Note9","Note10","Note11","Note12"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    */

    NotebookDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotebookDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    dbAdapter.open();
    notes = dbAdapter.getAllnotes();

    dbAdapter.close();

    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(), notes);
    setListAdapter(noteAdapter);

    //Полоска между записями в листе
    //getListView().setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), android.R.color.holo_purple));
    //getListView().setDividerHeight(1);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    launchNoteDetailActivity(MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.VIEW, position);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.long_press_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int rowPosition = info.position;
    Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(rowPosition);

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.edit:


            launchNoteDetailActivity(MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.EDIT, rowPosition);
            //Log.d("Menu click", "We pressed");
            return true;

        case R.id.delete:
            NotebookDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotebookDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            dbAdapter.open();
            dbAdapter.deleteNote(note.getId());
            notes.clear();
            notes.addAll(dbAdapter.getAllnotes());
            noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dbAdapter.close();
            Log.d("DELETE","NOTE");
    }


    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void launchNoteDetailActivity (MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch ftl, int position) {

    //grab the note information associated with  whatever note item we clicked on
    Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    //Created a new intent that launches our noteDetailActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteDetailActivity.class);
    //pass along the information of the note we clicked on to our noteDetailActivity
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA, note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA, note.getMessage());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA, note.getCategory());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_ID_EXTRA, note.getId());

    switch (ftl) {
        case VIEW:
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA, MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.VIEW);
            break;
        case EDIT:
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA, MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch.EDIT);
            break;
    }
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**NoteEditFragment:**

```
public class NoteEditFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageButton noteCatButton;
private Note.Category savedButtonCategory;
private AlertDialog categoryDialogObject,confirmDialogObject;
private EditText title,message;
private static final String MODIFIED_CATEGORY="Modified Category";

private boolean newNote = false;
private long noteId = 0;

public NoteEditFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
    if (bundle!=null){

        newNote=bundle.getBoolean(NoteDetailActivity.NEW_NOTE_EXTRA,false);
    }
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        savedButtonCategory=(Note.Category) savedInstanceState.get(MODIFIED_CATEGORY);

    }
    View fragmentLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    title=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
    message=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteMessage);
    noteCatButton=(ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteButton);
    Button savedButton=(Button) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.saveNote);

    Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();

    title.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA));
    message.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA));
    noteId=intent.getExtras().getLong(MainActivity.NOTE_ID_EXTRA,0);


    if (savedButtonCategory!=null)
    {
        noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(savedButtonCategory));
    }
    else if(!newNote) {
        Note.Category noteCat = (Note.Category) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA);
        savedButtonCategory = noteCat;
        noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(noteCat));
    }
    buildCategoryDialog();
    buildConfirmDialog();
    noteCatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            categoryDialogObject.show();
        }
    });
    savedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            confirmDialogObject.show();
        }
    });

    return fragmentLayout;

}

@Override
public  void  onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(MODIFIED_CATEGORY,savedButtonCategory);
}

private void  buildCategoryDialog(){

    final String[] categories=new String[]{"Personal","Technical","Quote","Finance"};
    AlertDialog.Builder categoryBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    categoryBuilder.setTitle("Choose Note Type");
    categoryBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            categoryDialogObject.cancel();
            switch (item) {
                case 0:

                    savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.PERSONAL;
                    noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.TECHNICAL;
                    noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.QUOTE;
                    noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pink);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.FINANCE;
                    noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    categoryDialogObject=categoryBuilder.create();
}
private void buildConfirmDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder =new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    confirmBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
    confirmBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure to save? ");
    confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d("save Note", "Note title:" + title.getText() + "Note message :" + message.getText() + "Note Category: " + savedButtonCategory);


            NotebookDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotebookDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            dbAdapter.open();
            if (newNote) {
                dbAdapter.createNote(title.getText() + "", message.getText() + "", (savedButtonCategory == null) ? Note.Category.PERSONAL : savedButtonCategory);
            }
            else {
                dbAdapter.updateNote(noteId, title.getText() + "", message.getText() + "", savedButtonCategory);

            }
            dbAdapter.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    confirmDialogObject=confirmBuilder.create();

}
```

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код активности, в которой вы выполняете операции отображения, обновления и удаления. Тогда будет проще Вам помочь.

Comment: Весь код-то зачем выкладывать? Мало кто его тут осилит. Оставьте только те места, что не работают и подробнее о них напишите.

Comment: скорее всего проблема с id и или position. кода адаптера нет, но есть подозрение что update'ится и удаляется не та запись. отладчик в помощь.